# MultiValueDictKeyError Django 1.8

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to import a file using forms.py. This code is the same code I used in another model and it worked, but this time it gives me this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /importraw 
Exception Value: "u'rawname'"
```

These are the snippets of code you need to know about:

Views.py

```
def importraw(request):
    form = UploadRaw(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        raw = Raw(title=request.POST['rawname'], file='raw_files/' + request.POST['file'])
        raw.save()
        handle_uploaded_raw(request.FILES["file"], request.POST["name"])
        raw.save()
    return redirect('/importations')
```

Urls.py:

```
url(r'^importraw$', views.importraw),
```

Forms.py:

```
class UploadRaw(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=120)
        file = forms.FileField()
```

Models.py:

```
class Raw(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='raw_files')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Index.html

```
<!--IMPORT-->
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Importer un fichier brut</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="/importraw", method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                  <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Structure</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <select name="id" id="id" class="struct form-control">
                                         {% for structure in structures %}
                                             <option value="{{ structure.name }}">{{ structure }}</option>
                                         {% endfor %}
                                     </select>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Nom du fichier brut</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <input type="text" name="rawname" id="rawname" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Fichier brut</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2" align="center">
                        <button type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Importer</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!--END-IMPORT-->
```

To know more about the exact error I am getting, please take a look at the following traceback:

```
**Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/importraw
Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.13
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'backoffice']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
Traceback:
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kaiss/Desktop/projet2/backoffice/views.py" in importraw
  232.         raw = Raw(title=request.POST['rawname'], file='raw_files/' + request.POST['file'])
File "/home/kaiss/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  322.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /importraw
Exception Value: "u'rawname'"**
```

I am using Python 2.7.13 and Django 1.8.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of UploadRaw? Why are you accessing `request.POST` directly?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention forms.py. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `rawname` is not in `request.POST`. In your case, the form is valid, therefore it would be better to get the value from the form's cleaned_data rather than `request.POST`.

```
if form.is_valid():
    raw = Raw(title=form.cleaned_data['title'], file='raw_files/' + request.POST['file'])
```

If you access data directly from request.POST, your code should handle this possibility, either checking if the key exists,

```
if 'rawname' in request.POST:
    rawname = request.POST['rawname']
```

or by using the `get()` method and specifying a default.

```
rawname = request.POST.get('rawname', '')
```

Finally, your form doesn't make sense. Regular forms don't have a `Meta` class, and fields should be defined inside the class, not inside the `Meta` class.

A simple [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) could look like:

```
class UploadRaw(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('title', 'file')
```

Then, [simplify your template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-template) to use `{{ form }}` at first. Once your view is working, you can until you get the view working. Then you can [render the fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) manually if you wish.

Comment: After using cleaned_data, I had another error: KeyError.

Comment: That's because your form does not make sense.

Comment: Well I used the exact same thing in another form and it is working fine, isn't this weird? Why is it working in one view and not working in another?

Comment: I don't know the difference between the two views, all I can do is comment on the code that you have shown.